# Error caused by rJava when loading ReporteRs package

Tags: r, rjava, reporters

I have problems loading `ReporteRs` in R. I get the following message:

```
Loading required package: ReporteRsjars
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: No CurrentVersion entry in Software/JavaSoft registry! Try 
re-installing Java and make sure R and Java have matching architectures.
Error: package ‘ReporteRsjars’ could not be loaded
```

I have Java version "1.8.0_25", `rJava`, `ggplot2` and `ReporteRsjars` installed.

Comment: The error message suggests you may have mismatched versions of R and Java, so please provide all possible details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a range of possible solutions for you to explore:

**Install the latest rJava version.**
Earlier versions may not work! Mirrors are not up-to-date, so go to the source at www.rforge.net: http://www.rforge.net/rJava/files/. Note the advice there
“Please use `install.packages('rJava',,'http://www.rforge.net/')` to install.”

That is almost correct. This actually works:
`install.packages('rJava', .libPaths()[1], 'http://www.rforge.net/')`
Watch the punctuation! The mysterious `“.libPaths()[1],”` just tells R to install the package in the primary library directory. For some reason, leaving the value blank doesn’t work, even though it should default.

**Tell R about the updated java version**
If you just changed your java version, make R aware of this by running R CMD javareconf from terminal.

**Add jvm.dll to your PATH and have it in the proper directory**
rJava, the R<->Java bridge, needs jvm.dll, but R will have trouble finding it. It resides in a folder like
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\bin\server
or 
C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\jre\bin\client
Wherever yours is, add that directory to your windows PATH variable. (Windows -> "Path" -> "Edit environment variables to for your account" -> PATH -> edit the value.)

You may already have Java on your PATH. If so you should find the client/server directory in the same Java "home" dir as the one already on your PATH.

It seems that rJava searches for jvm.dll in ~\Java\jre6\bin\client. However this folder didn´t exist on my system (jvm.dll was in ~\bin\server).  So one workaround is to make a copy of jvm.dll in a folder ~\bin\client\ and added this to the path.

**Define the path for R to find java**
options(java.home="C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/")
Change it appropriately

**Make sure your architectures match.** 
If you have Java in Program Files, it is 64-bit, so you ought to run R64. If you have Java in Program Files (x86), that's 32-bit, so you use plain 32-bit R.

**Re-launch R from the Windows Menu**
If R is running, quit.
From the Start Menu , Start R / RGUI, RStudio. This is very important, to make R pick up your PATH changes.

Comment: You have, I assume, run install.packages("packageName") and successfully downloaded the package.  Next, are you sure that the directory where the downloaded package data is located lies on your path?  Finally, are you spelling the package name correctly (case sensitive)?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I finally got around the issue, highly appreciate your response.